# How can I group input data lines in Pig, preserving order?

Tags: apache-pig

I have input data lines which are ordered (ranked), e.g.

```
 1,23
 1,45
 1,12
 2,74
 2,11
 2,8`
```

and want basically to group them on col1, but preserving the order of col2:

```
{1,{(23,45,12)}}
{2,{(74,11,8)}}
```

Standard GROUP is (imho) not an option as the inner bag
`{1,{(1,23),(1,45),(1,12))}}` does not guarantee that 23, 45, 12 are staying in that order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use RANK to add a line number to each row and then after you group order the inner group by that.

```
A = load 'data' AS (f1:int,f2:int);
B = RANK A;
```